# what is a cron job

Tags: cron

I see this every time I ask questions about backing up sql through php, but I don't know what is it, or how to install it, or how to use it in my computer(windows xp) to backup mysql database.

Comment: Try http://www.google.com/search?q=cron+job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron is a UNIX utility for running commands at specific times. A cron job is a such a commend when cron has been configured to run it.

On Windows you would likely use the Scheduler instead.

Comment: "Scheduled Tasks" is the Windows equivalent

Answer (score 3):

A cronjob is a unix term for a system process (cron) that allows you to schedule tasks to run at a later date under a specified set of privileges.
On Windows, I suggest you create a batch file for your backup, and use the Task Scheduler to run it at the desired time.

Answer (score 1):

cronjobs are available on Linux/Unix machines. These are scripts which you schedule to run at specific times (daily, hourly, monthly).

They are controlled by the unix command "crontab"

To list all of your cronjobs use `crontab -l`. To edit the list of cronjobs use `crontab -e`