# What is a cron file and how does it work?

Tags: php, file, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307675/what-is-a-cron-job)

A big question I know, I have researched it but I find the online blogs not much of a help, I know it is for executing a script at set intervals, but how would one go about creating one?

Also are there alternatives? What are the risk factors (if any), reliability?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Here is a nice, well-written introduction: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: On wikipedia it says (on unix like systems), if I include these in my php website, will they work on every system? Thanks Pekka, great help :)

Comment: whether cron jobs work or not depends what kind of web server your site is running on and what privileges you have on it. Read the introduction, they have nothing to do with your PHP web site really. They are a part of the operating system. On a shared web host, it depends on your hosting company whether they grant you access to them

Comment: Ok thank you Pekka :) Great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be referring to what are commonly known as Cron Jobs. These are tasks to be executed at scheduled intervals. You can find Cron Jobs on Unix systems, but you can also find a similar system in Windows called Task Scheduler.

You can use Cron Jobs to execute any executable or script on a Unix system, such as PHP scripts.