# Return the number of times my django model object was retrieved today

Tags: python, django

With a model like below, I want to return the number of times an object was retrieved today

```
class Watched(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             default=None)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The `Stamping` is another model with `created_at` and `updated_at`

Below is the example of what I want to achieve

```
a = Watched.objects.filter("only_the_ones_retrieved_today")
for b in a:
    return "b.count but only today's incremented values"
```

Comment: Is `Watched` the object, or the item that determines how many times an object (probably linked with a `ForeignKey` is watched by that user)?

Comment: Yeah it is linked with a ForeignKey. But for the object in ```Watched```, I want to return the number of times it has been retrieved today

Comment: Are you asking for a way to automatically increase `count` every time `Watched.objects.get` is called? Would calls to `filter` also count? Or are you counting requests in the View for a specific route? Are you creating a new entry for each day? Or are you resetting `count` at midnight? Not sure what your exact question is.

Comment: I only increment the ```count``` when ```get_or_create()``` method is used on the ```Watched``` object

Comment: I've edited and added a sample of what I'm looking forward to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `total_count` and a `daily_count` column, then reset the `daily_count` every day at midnight. For example:

```
class Watched(Stamping):
    ...
    total_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    daily_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

Then increase both fields from your `get_or_create()` handler.

You can then execute a piece of code every midnight that resets the `daily_count` for all `Watched` instances. I recommend you to write a [custom django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it via a [cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307675/what-is-a-cron-job) or similar:

```
Watched.objects.all().update(daily_count=0)
```